# Stop loading PHP page if javascript is not enabled

Tags: php, javascript, noscript

I am trying to stop loading my php page if the javascript is not enabled on user's computer.

below method working fine. However please let me know is it cross browsered and is it safe?

```
<noscript>
<?php
echo "Please Enable JavaScript in your browser!";
exit;
?>
</noscript>

  <div id="main">
    <!-- #header -->
    <div id="header"> 
        <div id="logo"><a href="homepage.php" title="Go to Homepage"><span><?php echo $Name;?></span></a></div>.....
```

Please let me know anyother professional way I can do it.

PS: Some of my user tried to disable JavaScript after page load.  This thing also affect some of my pages.  I am getting wrong values on submit since the js disabled.  I wanna overcome this situation please.

Comment: You cannot prevent a remote user from disabling JavaScript. If you want your pages to work without it, that's your problem to solve.  (And you're free to solve it by deciding it's OK for the page not to work, of course.)

Comment: netscape 2 does not support `<noscript>`. otherwise, you're safe.

Comment: @LifeInThe If anybody is using Netscape today I would be extremely surprised...

Comment: You cannot stop the page if JavaScript is disabled, but what you can do is have a page saying "JavaScript is disabled", and then use JavaScript to hide that and load the real page.

Comment: No, it's not cross-browser, and it's not ever going to work. PHP executes on the server. Javascript executes on the client. By the time the client receives the page and starts rendendering it, PHP has already shutdown/completed. You might as well just skip the php and have `<noscript>Turn on javascritp!<noscript>`

Comment: I don't understand why someone has given this question a down vote.

Comment: @Doorknob: I have a Power Macintosh (Performa) 6200 running Netscape 4.7 on Mac OS 9.1!

Comment: @garethl: I didn't downvote, but I'd guess it's because the question demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of how php and javascript are related, when/where code executes, etc...

Comment: @Doorknob: It's even got an ethernet port!

Comment: @Doorknob - i was making a joke. But someone is still using Netscape, so joke is on me!

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey: I don't *actually* use it, but I can!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can insert the tag

```
<title>Your title</title>    
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/badbrowser.html"></noscript>
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problmes....i think it will also redirect badbrowser.html if the js disabled after page load...

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the redirect certainly works the pages will still continue to load.

I have this problem and was hoping to find a solution. The answer is somewhere between the solutions so far offered:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/badbrowser.html">
<?php
exit;
?>
</noscript>
```

This starts the redirect but also prevents the rest of the PHP page loading.

Comment: If js is enabled then the page won't work at all...